# Feature count continues after turned off

Tags: qgis, feature-count

I have several vector layers for which I had at one point turned on "show feature count"   I've since turned it off, but every time I work on one of my layouts, I get constant pop-up messages that say "Task complete - Counting features in xxy". It seems to be really slowing down my project and is really annoying (I am aware I can turn off notifications).   So is there some feature I may be unaware of that will cause QGIS to count features, other than the "show feature count".

Comment: I'm using version 3.14.

Comment: sounds like a bug to me